# JPG files - different brightness in viewers

Tags: jpeg, image-compression, gamma

I have a single JPG file. If I open it with IrfanView, it is darker than the same file opened in PhotoShop (or in Firefox). What can cause this? The correct version is the one from Photoshop (or Firefox). I have also tried to open it manually with LibJPG-Turbo in C++ app, but the result is same as Irfan - dark.

Left: Irfan

Right: Firefox or Photoshop

[image]

From exif info tool, I have obtained also this:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.99
File Name                       : UAZK-B2-a-04-C-6890-002.JPG
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 6.5 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:05:11 15:51:20+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:05:11 19:04:32+02:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2020:05:11 19:04:32+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.02
Resolution Unit                 : inches
X Resolution                    : 300
Y Resolution                    : 300
Profile CMM Type                : Unknown (argl)
Profile Version                 : 2.2.0
Profile Class                   : Input Device Profile
Color Space Data                : RGB
Profile Connection Space        : XYZ
Profile Date Time               : 2017:03:10 13:05:37
Profile File Signature          : acsp
Primary Platform                : Microsoft Corporation
CMM Flags                       : Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer             :
Device Model                    :
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent                : Perceptual
Connection Space Illuminant     : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator                 : Unknown (argl)
Profile ID                      : 0
Profile Description             : CoCa 10.3.2017
Profile Copyright               : Copyright_free
Device Mfg Desc                 : proserv 600i
Device Model Desc               : Model
Media White Point               : 0.76875 0.82222 0.6651
Media Black Point               : 0.00369 0.00439 0.00339
Red Matrix Column               : 0.95648 0.32632 0.01039
Green Matrix Column             : 0.07027 0.99591 -0.27165
Blue Matrix Column              : 0.13623 -0.1051 1.32172
Red Tone Reproduction Curve     : (Binary data 14 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Green Tone Reproduction Curve   : (Binary data 14 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Blue Tone Reproduction Curve    : (Binary data 14 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Char Target                     : (Binary data 25129 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Image Width                     : 8408
Image Height                    : 6874
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:1:0 (4 2)
Image Size                      : 8408x6874
Megapixels                      : 57.8
```

The white point seems significantly different from what I have in other files, where values are around 1

Original file: http://www.levhart.cz/perry/test.jpg

Comment: Does it have  edits that are contained in a sidecar file that are only readable by the original editing software ?

Comment: There is no additional file. However, EXIF info contains some white info etc. See edit.

Comment: what is the colour profile?

Comment: @ths I have added full exif info

Comment: What are the color management settings in Windows, Irfanview, and Photoshop?  What does the image look like when opened with the default Windows viewer?  Can you add the original JPG to the question?

Comment: @xiota I have added link to the original file. Windows viewer shows the file correctly. I dont know the color managements. EXIF section from JPG file seems to be broken, since there is no EXIF info in Windows properties of file, but exiftool exports them

Comment: The different appearance in Irfanview vs other viewers is definitely related to the icc profile. When all metadata is stripped from the jpg, the "dark" version is shown. Irfanview seems unable to use the icc profile because nothing changes when I turn on color management. – That said, this question has no question.